# Rake aborted, no such file to load -- paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rake, paperclip

I'm trying to deploy a Rails3 app to Heroku, but am getting this 'Rake aborted' error when I rake db:create or rake db:migrate to heroku.

db:push does send the schema, indexes and data, but I get an 'Application Error' at the app.heroku url.

I've tried deleting and creating a new Heroku app, but I get the same problem.

Paperclip seems to be the cause. I've checked that paperclip is in the gemfile. I've updated all gems. I tried removing obvious dependencies from the gemfile. But I still get the 'rake aborted' error.

I'd appreciate any ideas or pointers to useful information to help me understand what's going on, and how to fix it.

This is the heroku db:create --trace

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- Paperclip
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:11
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/bin/rake:19
(in /app)
```

The heroku log file is long, and the only bit that looks relevant is

```
2011-04-26T02:57:28+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- Paperclip (LoadError)
```

My gem file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg', :require => 'pg'
gem 'paperclip', :require => 'paperclip'
gem 'rack-raw-upload'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'devise'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'cells'

group :development do
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    gem 'nifty-generators'
end

group :test do
    gem 'mocha'
end
```

Everything is working fine in my local Postgres dev environment.

Please let me know if I have missed any important info.

I appreciate any pointers that would help understand the best approach to debugging an issue like this. I'm lost as to where to start!

Thanks

Comment: Remove `, :require => 'paperclip'` and try `bundle install` again.

Comment: @zabba thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: If its possible, try installing the gem directly (gem install paperclip). Also, does it show up when you do a `gem list`? Or try adding a specific version to paperclip and then bundle install.

Comment: what actually triggers a "no such file to load" error during a rake? On a freshly deployed app with complete gem bundle, I'm having trouble understanding the sequence that would trigger this error?

Comment: @zabba thanks for your help. gem list does list paperclip, though two versions interestingly (2.3.11, 2.3.8). Installing the gem directly or specifying a version had no effect. Any other suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: the log when i push to heroku shows paperclip being installed with the gems bundle. So the gem should be present. I just tried removing paperclip from the gem file, bundle install, and push to heroku. db:migrate still generates "no such file to load --Paperclip" even when paperclip is not listed in the gemfile. I am very confused!

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting somewhere with this. I deleted all reference to paperclip in the gemfile, but gem list still listed paperclip. So I gem uninstalled all versions - clean slate. I restarted the development app, got the same error as Heroku. As expected. Push to Heroku, same error. Next I added Paperclip back to the gem file, local app works, Heroku still doesn't. Scratched head and pondered. Checked environments - development.rb lists `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"`. Nothing similar in production.rb. I guess I need to specify the path, but as what for Heroku?

Comment: `:command_path` I *think* is for the imagemagick commands...try setting it to the path returned by `which identify`.

Comment: @zabba actually i think you're right RE imagemagick. I have _finally_ resolved the Paperclip issue, traced it to the application.rb file

Comment: @zabba - perhaps you should post `:require => 'paperclip'` as the answer for me to accept. This was indeed the problem, I just needed to figure out where the problem was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, the answer to this was in the application.rb file. I had a line "require Paperclip", which i deleted and everything worked fine.

Comment: Turns out that I did need `:require => 'paperclip'` in applications.rb for my app to function properly. I added it again after migrations. So far no problems. We'll see what happens when I next migrate!